iperf3 is half speed when Linux is client? (and samba/sftp is very slow)
I'm using a Mellanox (now Nvidia?) ConnectX-3 card with a 10G fiber connection to my Unifi switch.  That same switch has a Windows PC connected at 1 Gbps.
However, when I transfer files from Linux to Windows using samba (SMB) or sftp it tops out at 60 MB/s.  (disk speed is over 1 GB/s so that's not the problem)
If I use iperf3 from Windows <-> Linux it shows 915 Mbps from Windows -> Linux but only 480 from Linux -> Windows.  This confirms the slow file transfers as well.
What is going on?
Here is my network adapter: (redacted mac)
4: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Here is my iperf3 from Windows to Linux:
[  5]   0.00-2.49   sec   273 MBytes   922 Mbits/sec                  sender

...and here is from Linux to Windows:
[  5]   0.00-3.26   sec   194 MBytes   498 Mbits/sec                  receiver


a sustained 1 GB/s to a disk is not a typical speed, but significantly higher than expected; are you perhaps confusing GigaByte with Gigabit, there, or are you confusing peak write rates with sustained write rates?

however, speed is limited by different factors in SMB and iperf; it makes very little sense to compare them. So, maybe rather address the problem you actually want to address! Is your problem that Samba shares are slow, or that you can't achieve the full 10 Gigabit per second via the interface for some other application than SMB?

I have seen weird things going on with wildly asymmetric speeds if for example the 'firmware' of the NIC isn't up-to-date. A good place to start looking is the kernel boot messages related to the 10GB NIC.
